# Spring 3 MVC: How to store € symbol from form?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I am using Spring 3 MVC and MySQL 5 as my DB.

I have created a form using Spring form tags for updating an object in my database.

I enter "Ticket price: €35" into one of this form's text input fields and save the item. Then when I view the item in a display page, the text appears as "Ticket price: ?35".

If I enter "Ticket price: €35" directly into the database using MySql Query Browser, then the euro symbol displays fine through the display page.

What do I need to do so that my Spring form saves the euro symbol correctly to the database?

---

**Update**:

Hi, I tried your suggestion, Bozho, with no luck.. my web.xml looks like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
         org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>




<servlet>
    <servlet-name>baseApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>baseApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the spring character encoding filter. In `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
         org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
```

And map it to the default servlet

Then, your MySQL connection string should look like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName?characterEncoding=utf8
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. I have tried adding this filter and unfortunately I'm still having the same issue, the euro symbol appears as a question mark. Any further thoughts?

Comment: If you still have the same issue, then your JDBC/DB thing is still not persisting the char as UTF-8. Try adding `useUnicode=yes` to connection string. MySQL has some oddness with regard to this all.

Comment: Great, I've now made that change to my dataSource URL as well as the previous changes to web.xml as above. Now when I save the form with a € I get an exception: 
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Data truncation: Data truncated for column 'description' at row 1

. 'description' is the field that I'm entering the € into and it has a MySQL data type of TEXT.

Any thoughts on why I'm getting this exception?

Comment: perhaps your column doesn't have enough length?

Comment: I'm not sure column length is the problem.. the column is of type TEXT and the only value i'm entering into it is €, i.e. just the single character... odd.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I've started a new question for my data truncation error here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230561/spring-3-mvc-mysql-cannot-store--character

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure, that the encoding of your string containing the € is set to the correct encoding (same of your table). I would suggest to use UTF-8

Comment: -1. Internal representation of all `String` s in Java is UTF-16. What he need is a correct transformation chain - from the page encoding to UTF-16 (performed by `CharacterEncodingFilter`) and from UTF-16 to the database encoding (performed by JDBC driver).

Comment: It does not matter, whether he sets the encoding of his string to UTF-16 first and then converts it to the database encoding by JDBC, or if he converts it to UTF-8 from the webpage and the JDBC does not have to to any further conversion or do I miss something?

Comment: yes you have.  Read @axtavt's answer again ... carefully.  ALL Java Strings are UTF-16.  Period.

Comment: I don't agree - sorry: you can set the encoding of strings in java to ANY encoding. I don't care if the deepest inner of java reencode it to UTF-16 and when I use the string it automatically reencodes it back to UTF-8 for me. But it IS possible to define the encoding of a string to UTF-8 and use it as such. See: java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder